# Solve for Differential Equations by using regular perturbation method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

carry out regular perturbation calculation for $\epsilon$ satisfying
 $$x''(t)+x(t)=\epsilon x^2(t)$$
correct to the second order in the small parameter $\epsilon$.
then use the result  to perform a renormalization calculation, straightforwardly
assuming that the lowest order correction to the period of the system
is of order $\epsilon^2$, not (the erroneous) $\epsilon$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

This system is conservative, multiply with $2 x'$ and integrate to get
$$
(x')^2+x^2(1-ϵ\tfrac23x)=R^2=const.
$$
Write this as $(x')^2+u(x)^2=R^2$. This circle equation can now be parametrized like a circle, with $x'(t)=R\cos\varphi(t)$, and then consequently $R\sinφ(t)=u(x(t))=x(t)\sqrt{1-ϵ\tfrac23x(t)}$.

---

Now find the inverse function $v$ to $u$ so that $x=v(R\sinφ)$. Then its derivative and the circle equation lead to the identity
$$
R\cosφ=x'=v'(R\sinφ)R\cosφ\,φ',
\\
1=v'(R\sinφ)\,φ'.
$$
This allows to compute the period of $x$ as
$$
T=\int_0^{2\pi}v'(R\sinφ)\,dφ
$$

---

To find the first terms of the expansion of $v$, bring $u=x\sqrt{1-ϵ\tfrac23x}$ into fixed-point form and apply the binomial series for the power $-1/2$ to give
$$
x=u\left(1-2\fracϵ3x\right)^{-1/2}=u\left(1+\fracϵ3x+\frac{ϵ^2}6x^2 + \frac{5}{54}(ϵx)^3 + \frac{35}{648}(ϵx)^4 +O(ϵ^5)\right)
$$
Iterating this relation gives, starting from $x=u+O(ϵ)$,
\begin{align}
x&=u\left(1+\fracϵ3u+O(ϵ^2)\right)
\\&\vdots\\
x=v(u)&=u + \frac13ϵu^2 + \frac{5}{18}ϵ^2u^3 + \frac{8}{27}ϵ^3u^4 + \frac{77}{216}ϵ^4u^5 +O(ϵ^5)\\
v'(u)&=1 + \frac23ϵu + \frac{5}{6}ϵ^2u^2 + \frac{32}{27}ϵ^3u^3 + \frac{385}{216}ϵ^4u^4 +O(ϵ^5)
\end{align}
so that, using that odd powers of the sine integrate to zero and the constant part of $\sin^{2k}φ$ is $\frac{\binom{2k}{k}}{2^{2k}}$,
\begin{align}
T&=2\pi+\int_0^{2\pi}\left[\frac23ϵR\sinφ + \frac{5}{6}(ϵR)^2\sin^2φ + \frac{32}{27}(ϵR)^3\sin^3φ + \frac{385}{216}(ϵR)^4\sin^4φ +O(ϵ^5)\right]\,dφ
\\
&=2\pi\left(1+\frac{5}{6}(ϵR)^2\frac{\binom{2}{1}}{2^2}+\frac{385}{216}(ϵR)^4\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{2^4}+O(ϵ^6)\right)
=2\pi\left(1+\frac{5}{12}(ϵR)^2+\frac{385}{576}(ϵR)^4+O(ϵ^6)\right).
\end{align}